# Nested iterator in model not working?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, precondition

I am trying to iterate through 2 folders (1 for points, and 1 for polygons) and use the output values as inputs for another submodel that applies IDW, Focal Statistics, and finally a Clip (to a polygon) to convert a series of points into a raster (clipped to the individual polygons). I have created a batch iterator tool to overcome the one iterator restriction within a model. I have tried multiple configurations of this (1 iterator + iterator submodel, 2 iterator submodels, etc...) without success. I have also tried to use the "Collect Values" tool, but when I do this, it only allows me to connect to the Points to Raster submodel as Preconditions, not inputs.

What am I doing wrong here?

Below are the two submodels (Batch_Iterator_tool & Points to Raster tool) and the main model that I am trying to build. 
Batch iterator tool submodel:
     [image]

Points to Raster tool submodel:
     [image]

Main Model:
     [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "collect values" you are creating a LIST of values. So your sub-model batch iterator is passing out a LIST of featureclasses which were in the workspace Individual_Boundaries.

Now look at the Help file for your [IDW](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/idw.htm) and [Clip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm#GUID-373858DC-75BF-4816-880B-B27DFD0DB1E6) tool especially the syntax section. This is telling what the tool takes as inputs and produces as outputs. Where does it say that the IDW tool takes a LIST of inputs? It does not. Where does it say the Clip tool takes a LIST of inputs? It does not.  This is why it won't allow you to connect as you are attempting to connect inappropriate inputs to the tool.

Now having read the help file and understood what the tools take as inputs you will realise that the logic of your model is currently flawed, you are trying to pass lists around when the tools take only single layers. You need to rethink the logic.

I assume what is `VSECOM Layer` is actually the output of the iterator in your master model? Are you then wanting to clip the resulting focal stats output by many individual boundaries? Currently it is not clear what you want interpolated and clipped with.

Comment: Yes, I want to clip the interpolated (IDW + Focal Stats) layer to the individual boundaries. BTW- Your answer about the Collect Values/List thing was correct.

Comment: So, I just removed that from the model. It seems the I need to do 2 additional things to get this to work: 1) IDW only allows the output name to be 13 char long for some reason. So %Name% will not work. I am going to try something like ec_%n% to keep it short. 2) When I run IDW  against the iterated point files, using ec_%n% as the output name, it starts to work but then fails at "ec_3." The error says `ERROR 010092: Invalid output extent.
Failed to execute (IDW).` I think this means I need to use something other than %n%.